# Can someone explain to me what's the difference between 'Below' and 'Beneath'?

Tags: word-usage

It's quite confusing for me to understand the difference between these two words. The sentences:

- > Read below all the information that you may need.
- > Read beneath all the information that you may need.

Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "is that correct?" Are you asking *which* of them is correct in this context?

Comment: I was asking if both sentences are correct. I would like to know if the sentences still have the same meaning, even though I changed the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- All the information you may need is below.
- Below is all the information you may need.

Below is used for referring to something that is not at the same level as something else: underneath it. Text can be said to be below some other thing on a page. Under it.

- The comments were **beneath me**. [not worth my responding to]

Beneath is used to mean **below in a moral sense**.

(I have not addressed all the uses of below, just the ones in the context presented).

Answer (score 0):

> [Below](https://www.englishgrammar.org/beneath/) is mainly used in cases where an object is not directly under another.
>
> - We could find something below the surface of the water.
> - Millions of people still live below the poverty line. (Somewhere below > - that hypothetical line separating the poor from the rich)
>
> Below is also used in measurements where we think of a vertical scale.
>
> - This part of the country is below sea level.

While

> Beneath is mainly used in a literal or formal style.
>
> - Coral reefs that lie beneath the waters were a beautiful sight.
> - They sat beneath a huge mango tree.

(www.englishgrammar.org)

Comment: Isn't it unbelievable to you that I answered one aspect of the question and you answered another, and we were both canned.

Comment: @Lambie - I think they are both valid answers....

Comment: Exactly, they are. I actually posted a question about this in the ELL meta forum.

Comment: @Lambie - yes, that makes sense.

Comment: @Lambie what do you mean by *we were both canned*?